# my flutter app login first to get firebase data why get this fault

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

I first cleared all the cache records. When I executed my APP for the first login, the code popped up an error saying that id is equal to null, but I can read the data when I jump to other pages. I can’t understand the reason. What can I do to solve this problam?

I use flutter framework

this is my code

```
Future<void> remoteToLocal() async {
final data = await _userDoc.get();
var prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
int originalRemoteDataDate = data.data['remote_data_date'] == null ? 0 : data.data['remote_data_date'];

Directory appDocDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
String dbPath = appDocDirectory.path + '/temp$_uid.db';
DatabaseFactory dbFactory = databaseFactoryIo;
Database db = await dbFactory.openDatabase(dbPath);

var store = StoreRef<String, dynamic>.main();

await store.record('vip').put(db, data.data['vip']!=false?{
  'buy_time': ts.Timestamp.parse(data.data['vip']['buy_time'].toString()),
  'expire_time': ts.Timestamp.parse(data.data['vip']['expire_time'].toString()),
  'status': data.data['vip']['status']
}:false);

var course = List();
await data.data['course'].forEach((each) {
  course.add({
    'period': each['period'],
    'records': each['records'],
    'resultData': each['resultData'],
    'start': ts.Timestamp.parse(each['start'].toString()),
    'survey': each['survey'],
  });
});
await store.record('course').put(db, course);
await store.record('records').put(db, data.data['records']);
await store.record('advanceType').put(db, data.data['advanceType']);
await store.record('basicType').put(db, data.data['basicType']);
await store.record('staff').put(db, data.data['staff']);
await store.record('admin').put(db, data.data['admin']);

await prefs.setInt('_local_data_date', originalRemoteDataDate);
//await db.close();
}
```

this is my errorCode

> E/flutter (28436): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method 'forEach' was called on null.
>
> E/flutter (28436): Tried calling: forEach(Closure: (dynamic) => Null)

[image]

Comment: this is my error code

Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method 'forEach' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: forEach(Closure: (dynamic) => Null)

Comment: please check what is returned by `_userDoc.get()` and assigned to `data`

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion I will try

Comment: what is the _userDoc.get() have foreach method that I can't find ,can you tell me , please! @Chandan

Comment: in your shared code 2 line.

Comment: @Chandan the data is a list ,It has get value, but it still poped up the error

Comment: can you share sample data of what is returned

Comment: @Chandan I posted the data sample, you can see